# mongodb aggregating and grouping nested objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a several collections:

```
User {
 items: [ObjectID(n)]
}

Items {
 _id: ObjectID(n),
 name: '',
 categories: [ObjectID(n)]
}

Categories {
 _id: ObjectID(n),
 name: ''
}
```

I Use query below to lookup items:

```
db.Users.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                _id: ObjectId("n")
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: "$items"
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Items",
                localField: "items",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "items"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: "$items"
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                items: { $push: "$items" }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Now I populate **Users.items** but i cannot deal with categories inside items. I Use code below to get categories.

```
db.Users.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                _id: ObjectId("n")
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: "$items"
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Items",
                localField: "items",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "items"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: "$items"
        }, {
            $unwind: "$items.categories"
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Categories",
                localField: "items.categories",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "items.categories"
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                items: { $push: "$items" }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

But I cannot perform correct grouping.

Any ideas how to properly group categories inside items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on track so far. Now you just have to do nested grouping to merge the structure.So you'll need two groups at the end. First group by user id and item id and push the unique users items along with the categories and final grouping by user id and push the item with its categories.

```
db.User.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            _id: 123
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$items"
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Items",
            localField: "items",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "userItems"
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$userItems"
    }, {
        $unwind: "$userItems.categories"
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Categories",
            localField: "userItems.categories",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "categoryItems"
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                id: "$_id",
                itemId: "$userItems._id"
            },
            items: {
                $addToSet: "$items"
            },
            categories: {
                $push: "$categoryItems"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.id",
            itemCategories: {
                $push: {
                    items: "$items",
                    categories: "$categories"
                }
            }
        }
    }]
);
```

Sample Output:

```
{
    "_id": 123,
    "itemCategories": [{
        "items": [456],
        "categories": [
            [{
                "_id": 789
            }],
            [{
                "_id": 890
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "items": [234],
        "categories": [
            [{
                "_id": 567
            }],
            [{
                "_id": 678
            }]
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, almost what I want!